# Laravel - Merge two tables, then remove entries based on a where query

Tags: laravel, sqlite

I have a database of fruit, and lets say I want all the red fruit from it:

```php
$allfruit = DB::table('fruits')->Where("color","=","red")->paginate(10);
```

I also have a table of user's least favourite fruit. If a user is logged in I'm trying to pass their ID through to get a list of all their hated fruit:

```laravel
$leastfav = DB::table('dislikes')->Where("userID","=",Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

Now what I'd like to do is remove all the entries from `$allfruit` that appear in the 'dislikes' table with that user's ID.

What I've tried is something like:

```
$allfruit = DB::table('fruits')->Where("color","=","red")->merge($leastfav)->where(fruits.ID,"!=", "dislikes.fruitID")->paginate(10);
```

My DB is SQLite if that helps. Thanks

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `whereNotExists` (the inverse of [whereExists()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-exists-clauses)):

```
$allfruitQuery = DB::table('fruits')->where('color', 'red');

if (auth()->check()) {
    $allfruitQuery->whereNotExists(function ($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw(1))
            ->from('dislikes')
            ->where('userID', auth()->id())
            ->whereRaw('fruits.ID = dislikes.fruitID');
    });
}

$allfuit = $allfruitQuery->paginate(10);
```

Alternatively, (if you're using 5.2+) you could use `when()`:

```
$allfuit = DB::table('fruits')->where('color', 'red')
    ->when(auth()->check(), function ($query) {
        $query->whereNotExists(function ($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                ->from('dislikes')
                ->where('userID', auth()->id())
                ->whereRaw('fruits.ID = dislikes.fruitID');
        });
    })
    ->paginate(10);
```